# Map an the values from an array of objects to another array of arrays to match a new data structure

Tags: javascript, lodash

How do I get the requiredObject data structure from the rows and columns variable? I know I need to use some higher-order array methods like map, etc. I just find the right combination
[image]

Comment: Posting image for code is bad practice. Is it to avoid some teacher finding his given homework online ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use currently, I am sure there's a better looking solution

```
let colArray = columns.columns.map(col => col.name)

let transfromedData = []
rows.forEach(row => {
  let temp = {};
  colArray.forEach((key, i) => {
      temp[key] = row[i];
    })
    transfromedData.push(temp)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const sortedColums = columns.columns.sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value).map(x=>x.name)
  const output = rows.map(x => { const entry = {}; x.map((val, idx) => entry[sortedColums[idx]] = val); return entry})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 